# Python: how to check entries with white spaces in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` containing the information of car brands. For instance,

```
df['Car_Brand'][1]
'HYUNDAI                       '
```

where the length of each entries is the same `len(df['Car_Brand'][1])=30`. I can also have entries with only white spaces.

```
df['Car_Brand'] 

0          TOYOTA                        
1          HYUNDAI                       
2                                        
3                                        
4                                        
5          OPEL                          
6                                        
7          JAGUAR
```

where 
`df['Car_Brand'][2] 
'                              '`

I would like to drop from the dataframe all the entries with white spaces and reduce the size of the others. Finally:

```
df['Car_Brand'][1]
'HYUNDAI                       '
```

becomes

```
df['Car_Brand'][1]
'HYUNDAI'
```

I started to remove the withe spaces, in this way:

```
tmp = df['Car_Brand'].str.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Is last paragraph in question OK? Or typo?

Answer (score 1):

using [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and convert it to `bool` to filter the empty ones

```
df['Car_Brand'] = df['Car_Brand'].strip()

df[df['Car_Brand'].astype(bool)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems need:

```
s = df['Car_Brand']
s1 = s[s != ''].reset_index(drop=True)
#if multiple whitespaces
#s1 = s[s.str.strip() != ''].reset_index(drop=True)
print (s1)
0     TOYOTA
1    HYUNDAI
2       OPEL
3     JAGUAR
Name: Car_Brand, dtype: object
```

If multiple `whitespace`s:

```
s = df[~df['Car_Brand'].str.contains('^\s+$')]
```